# Using enumset in Guava's joiner

Tags: guava, enumset, joiner

I am working on converting an enumset into a string of values that are in the enumset. At the moment, I am using `Joiner.on(',').join(enumset))` to create a string of values. However, I am wondering what are the ordering guarantees that enumset provides?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are guarantees. See the Javadoc for [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

> The iterator returned by the iterator method traverses the elements in
>   their natural order (**the order in which the enum constants are
>   declared**). The returned iterator is weakly consistent: it will never
>   throw ConcurrentModificationException and it may or may not show the
>   effects of any modifications to the set that occur while the iteration
>   is in progress.